# OpenGL ES for Android requires 2.0 commands for 3.0 context?

Tags: java, opengl-es

I'm rendering video using

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            decodedFrame.width[j],
                            decodedFrame.height[j],
                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                            null);
```

I was using `GL_RED`  in place of `GL_LUMINANCE` because I thougth that, since im using OpenGL `#version 320 es` in my shader, I need to use OpenGL 3.x commands like GL_RED. But GL_RED wont work, only GL_LUMINANCE does.

Here's how I'm creating the context:

```
        eglDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        if (eglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglGetDisplay failed");
        }

        int[] version = new int[2];
        if (!egl.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglInitialize failed");
        }

        EGLConfig eglConfig = chooseEglConfig();
        eglContext = createContext(egl, eglDisplay, eglConfig);

        eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, surfaceTexture, null);

        if (eglSurface == null || eglSurface == EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("GL Error: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl.eglGetError()));
        }

        if (!egl.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("GL make current error: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl.eglGetError()));
        }

private EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay eglDisplay, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
        int[] attribList = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3, EGL10.EGL_NONE};
        return egl.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attribList);
    }

    private EGLConfig chooseEglConfig() {
        int[] configsCount = new int[1];
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
        int[] configSpec = getConfig();

        if (!egl.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configSpec, configs, 1, configsCount)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to choose config: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl.eglGetError()));
        } else if (configsCount[0] > 0) {
            return configs[0];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see Im using `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION`, 3

I also imported everything from GLES30:

```
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glDrawArrays;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_LINEAR;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_STREAM_DRAW;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TEXTURE0;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glActiveTexture;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glBindBuffer;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glBindTexture;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glBufferData;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glBufferSubData;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glGenBuffers;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glGenTextures;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glGetUniformLocation;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glTexImage2D;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glTexParameteri;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glTexSubImage2D;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glUniform1f;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.glUniform1i;
    import static android.opengl.GLES30.GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER;
```

But I needed to import `GL_LUMINANCE` from GLES20 for it to work

So why do I need to use `GL_LUMINANCE`?
Here's how I'm creating and using the texture:

```
    if (!initiatedTextures)
        {
            //LOG << "initiatedTextures";
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "initiating textures");
            //TODO: delete these textures
            glGenTextures(1, textureId);


            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId.get(0));
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    0,
                    GL_LUMINANCE,
                    2304,
                    1296,
                    0,
                    GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    null);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            initiatedTextures = true;
        }

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId.get(0));

        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                2304,
                1296,
                GL_LUMINANCE,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                buffer);
```

If I simply exchange all the 3 `GL_LUMINANCE` by `GL_RED` the textures aren't filled at all.

Comment: "*import GL_LUMINANCE from GLES20*" `GL_LUMINANCE` is still part of ES 3.0. You don't have to "import" it from anywhere.

Comment: If you can't use `GL_RED` (presumably due to an OpenGL error of some kind?), that's probably an indicator that you're using an incompatible internal format. But since you didn't show us how you created the texture, that's pure speculation.

Comment: @NicolBolas I updated with the information on how I create and fill the texture

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL ES, the internal format you use is required to match the pixel transfer format you use. You used the `GL_LUMINANCE` internal format when you defined your texture. Therefore, all pixel transfers to/from that texture *must* use the `GL_LUMINANCE` pixel transfer format.

If you had used `GL_RED` as the internal format, you could/would be required to use the `GL_RED` pixel transfer format. `GL_RED` as an internal format is an ES 3.0 feature, not available in ES 2.0.